# how can I implement a Unity fps sprinting animation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I'm currently working on an FPS game and I have these hand models as well as weapons. But I want it so that if I press the **W key** (move forward) it plays the sprinting animation with the arms. I initially thought of coding it like, `if(Input.getkeydown(keycode.w))animation.play` or something like that. But I'm using the character controller which doesn't use that. It uses the  `Input.getaxisraw`. How should I implement this with the character controller?

**Thank you a ton in advance**

Comment: @AmirHashempour Please don't put things like "FPS" inside `code blocks`. They are not code and so it is not an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a basic animator controller. You can define all your states (Idle, Crouch, Jump, Sprint, Aim) and define the transitions between them. You may then add parameters like floats, triggers and booleans as conditions to transition between these states.

[image]

In the above example, if you want to move to a crouch state, you would use

```
GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Crouch", true);
```

Or for another example, if you want to move from Run to Walk. The transition (The blue lines indicating the movement from one state to another) will have a condition to move from walk to run and back based on the float parameter "Speed". if Speed>x, move from walk to run. else move from run to walk. In this case you would set

```
GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("Speed", floatValueHere)
```

and the controller will take care of the animation transitions.
This is just a pointing to the right direction. you will need to watch a couple of videos on animator controllers [Check Unity's simple 8 minute explanation here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeZkctmoBPw) Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah but how would that work with the character controller? My current movement code is, (float x = Input.getaxisraw("horizontal");  how would work with the animator? Because it's just one line of code. Thank you very much!

Comment: Once you get the value of x in the update loop, right under it you would check for the value of x. let's say x<=0.4 means walk and x>0.4 means run. so you would do:

float x = Input.getaxisraw("horizontal");
GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("Speed", x)

if you're using a bool for a parameter instead, 

float x = Input.getaxisraw("horizontal");
if(x<=0.4)
GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("run", false)
else
GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("run", true)

and your animator would make the transition simply based on what parameters you set. Make sure the transitions are defined well.